# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "location"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I'm getting this error after upgrading to Rails 5.2.2 from 4.2.10.

I am using the [activerecord-postgis-adapter](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter) to make models locatable.

Now, I'm getting this error due to some bad sql.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "location"
LINE 1: ..."locatable_type" = $1 WHERE "users"."id" = $2 AND "location"...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "users"."id" AS t0_r0, "users"."username" AS t0_r1, "users"."created_at" AS t0_r2, ..., FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "locations" ON "locations"."locatable_id" = "users"."id" AND "locations"."locatable_type" = $1 WHERE "users"."id" = $2 AND "location"."locatable_type" = $3 LIMIT $4
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:611:in `async_exec_params'
Caused by PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "location"
LINE 1: ..."locatable_type" = $1 WHERE "users"."id" = $2 AND "location"...
```

The problem is, there is no `location` table, and all I'm doing is creating the record with `Location.create(:locatable_type => "User", :locatable_id => id, :point => "POINT(0 0)")`

It's like its forgetting to pluralize the location model name.

Comment: Add schema.rb, Location and User models, please

Comment: Is `Location` an ActiveRecord (i.e. does it correspond to a `locations` table)? If not, you might need to derive `Location` from ActiveModel instead (without a table) or set the table name manually on the class.